# Show that R is a PID if R is a local noetherian integral domain, whose unique maximal ideal is non-trivial and principal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let R be a local noetherian integral domain, whose unique maximal ideal is
non-trivial and principal.

I need to show that R is a PID.

---

We have the hint that we should use Nakayamas Lemma. However, I have no idea how that should help.

---

What I tried:

Let $(m)$ be the unique maximal ideal in $R$ and $I$ be any ideal. So: $I = (a_1,...,a_n) \subset (m)$.

So we get $m \,|\, a_i$ for all $i$. With Nakayama we get: $r \in (m) \iff m\,|\,r \iff (\forall x\in R: \,1-rx \in R^*)$

But I don't get anything useful here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints.** Let $J=\bigcap_{r\ge1}(m^r)$. Show that $J=mJ$, and then use Nakayama. Write $I=m^k(b_1,...,b_n)$ with not all $b_i$ in $(m)$.

Comment: $mJ=J$ because $\cap_{r \geq 1} (m^r) = \cap_{r \geq 2} (m^r)$ since $(m^2) \subset (m)$. Also, $J$ is finitely generated since $R$ is noetherian. Now see it as a $R$-module, so we can apply Nakayama and get $J=0$. I see how we can write $I$ in such a form (just pull out $m^k$ with $k$ maximal). But how do we get a generator for $I$ now? I don't really see the connection to $J=0$.

Comment: Once noname’s claim holds, any element $x$ can be written as some power of the generator $a$ of the maximal ideal times something not in the maximal ideal, ie we can write $x=a^nu$ with $u$ unit if $x \neq 0$, and thus any principal ideal is a power of $m$, and the conclusion follows.